# Using a Script to Create Buckets in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I was wondering if it was possible to create a script to create my own buckets in elasticsearch. I've seen bucket_script, but that just runs a script on all existing buckets. I need to be able to use my own algorithm to sort the documents into buckets, as my use case is not covered by the existing bucket options.

Comment: The `terms` aggregation allows scripts, but it sounds like you might be looking for the scripted metric aggregation.

Comment: I've tried using the scripted metric aggragation, but I can't return the items to make my own buckets. I would have return IDs and the client would make the buckets.